# Not able to publish my library in private repo hosted on gemfury

Tags: npm, npm-publish, gem-fury

I am getting this error while publishing my library to gemfury.

```
npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable - PUT https://npm-proxy.fury.io/<username>/@<scope>%2f<package-name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure to use the **full access token** which will be available in the last tab of [this](https://manage.fury.io/manage/%3Caccount%3E/tokens/api) page. You can also use the **push token** which can be generated from the second tab of the [same](https://manage.fury.io/manage/%3Caccount%3E/tokens/api) page for added security.

*Note: replace **`<account>`** in the URL with your account slug*